# Why does this simple_fields_for not execute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, simple-form, nested-forms, simple-form-for

I have two models:

```
class PortStock < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :closed_positions
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :closed_positions
end

class ClosedPosition < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :closer, class_name: "PortStock", foreign_key: "closer_id"
  belongs_to :closed, class_name: "PortStock", foreign_key: "port_stock_id" 
end
```

I know this association works, because I have tested it otherwise.

I then have a form partial at `views/port_stocks/sell/_form.html.erb` that looks like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for @port_stock, url: port_stocks_sell_order_path, method: :post do |f| %>
   <% @port_stocks.each do |port_stock| %>
       <%= f.simple_fields_for :closed_positions, html: { class: "form-inline" } do |c| %>
          <%= c.input_field :num_units, id: "sell-ps-#{port_stock.id}", class: "form-control mx-sm-3" %>
       <% end %>
   <% end %>
  <%= f.button :submit, "Sell Stock", class:"btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

But, when the HTML is rendered, it doesn't render any of the text fields within the `simple_fields_for`.

If I put a `binding.pry` right before the `f.simple_fields_for` line, it halts execution. If I put it right after, it doesn't. That tells me that the `simple_fields_for` isn't being executed.

But per [the docs](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Nested-Models) that's how I should do it.

What am I missing? Why does this not render the form fields within the `simple_fields_for`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

I didn't actually `build` the `closed_positions` in my controller.

So once I added this code to my controller:

```
@port_stock.closed_positions.build
```

That worked like a charm.